# Adding views using for loop to scrollable view in appcelerator

Tags: arrays, view, appcelerator, scrollable

Can anyone please tell me how to add an array of views using a for loop to a scrollable view in android. The answers that I surfed online are not giving me a clear idea and are way too confusing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) two options. If you have a lot of work going on for each list item (e.g. showing a thumbnail for a picture) then you may want to use the second approach. Otherwise, you may just use this simple approach (where I show statistics for a number of species - layout controlled in a separate controller). `stats` is my list:

```
function showSpecies(stats) {
    _.each(stats, function(record){
        $.form.add(Alloy.createController('viewStatsRow', {record:record}).getView());
    });
}
```

In this example I have more work going on for "building" every item. So to avoid locking the thread I use a list as a "queue" and just handles the first item - and then call the function with the remaining list until it is empty:

```
var work = [];
function showNextItem(work,first){
    if(work && work.length > 0){
        // Progressively show list....
        if($.boastList && $.boastList.sections[0]){
            var list = [];
            list.push(buildOneItem(work.shift()));  // Take first element
            if(first){
                $.boastList.sections[0].items = list;  // Replace list
            }else{
                $.boastList.sections[0].appendItems(list);  // append item
            }
            // Free queue to allow other actions
            setTimeout(function(){
                showNextItem(work); // Call recursively...
            },30);
        }
    }else{
        // All boasts shown...
    }
}

function showBoastlist(){
    work = [];
    DataFactory.boasts.find({}, {$sort:{sortTime:-1}}, function(result){
        result.forEach(function(record) {
            work.push(record);
        });
    });
    showNextItem(work,true);
}
```

The `buildOneItem` function just returns an item ready to be added to the view.

Not sure if this was what you asked for - but hope you can use it ;-)

Happy coding!

/John